# Can I run Ubuntu directly under Windows 8?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, hyper-v

Text below is extract from the article, [Windows 8 Tip: Virtualize with Hyper-V](http://winsupersite.com/article/windows8/windows-8-tip-virtualize-hyperv-143521).

> Better still, Windows Virtual PC offered a feature called XP Mode,
>   free for users of Windows 7 Professional, Enterprise, and Ultimate,
>   which included a full working copy of Windows XP with Service Pack 3.
>   But the big deal here is that as you installed applications in the
>   virtual copy of XP, they would be made available through Windows 7’s
>   Start Menu. And you could run these applications, side-by-side, with
>   Windows 7 applications on the Windows 7 desktop. It was a seamless,
>   integrated experience, ideal for those one-off application
>   compatibility issues.

I was thinking to install VirtualBox in Windows 8 and then run Ubuntu as guess OS. Since Hyper-V is a Type-0 hipervisor, may I know does this bring the same benefit if I have Ubuntu Linux install as a virtual guess OS? Meaning, if I turning the Ubuntu on (the guess OS), does the Ubuntu still able to access the hardware information like nVidia display card or processor information?

I'm just curious to know can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With VirtualBox, the VM is shown a generic graphics card that VirtualBox handles (e.g., hardware acceleration will work if you have the necessary hardware and tell it to); same with the processors. Hyper-V most likely does the same thing because giving an OS information that the graphics card or processor can handle X and then limiting it to X/2 is confusing. Off of [these tests](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=32904), VirtualBox is faster than Hyper-V, but your mileage may vary. (VirtualBox also has better support for Linux distros  than Hyper-V.)

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "better support" bit, since I'd be interested in knowing as well what advantages VirtualBox offers in this case over Hyper-V. As per [this page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794868%28WS.10%29.aspx), Ubuntu is a supported guest OS and "integration services are built-in and do not require a separate download and installation". These include "IDE, SCSI, networking, and mouse" drivers as well as "Time synchronization, operating system shutdown, and heartbeat" services.

Comment: That's new. Those services are in VirtualBox also, and VB supports the latest version of Ubuntu along with [many others](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Guest_OSes).

Comment: Support for "many others" is fine, but specifically talking about Ubuntu, any major differences between the VMs? What I want to know is, given Hyper-V comes pre-installed in Win8, why should one download and install VirtualBox when it comes to Ubuntu?

Comment: It's a matter of personal preference; I would go with VB because it supports the latest version and it has had Linux support for longer, giving the devs more time to see and fix bugs. Also, it's free, so you can remove it if you don't like it.

Comment: Thanks Brayden (guess I'll have to uninstall/disable Hyper-V since having both installed is a no-no as per the link you gave).